# Questions about using Regex Search & Replace in gedit

Tags: python, gedit, regex

I am trying to use the [Regex Search & Replace plugin](http://halfhourhacks.blogspot.com/2008/03/gedit-regular-expression-plugin.html) of gedit.

1. I want to search for a digit that
   repeats 2 or 3 times, so I thought
   the regex was

   ```
   [0-9]\{2,3\}
   ```

   But it doesn't match the targets it
   should, such as "22".
2. I want to find a word "Notes"
   exactly, so I thought it would be

   ```
   \<Notes\>
   ```

   But it doesn't work either.
3. How to add a "#" in front of a
   string of any three digits
   "[0-9][0-9][0-9]"? e.g. "123" becomes "#123".

I was wondering if I made some mistake? I am using [Basic Regex](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html). What type of Regex is used in the plugin? How can I learn how to use this plugin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not need to escape your regex characters. Your first example should be:

```
[0-9]{2,3}
```

Your second example should be:

```
\bNote\b
```

For the third situation, you'll need to match things before and after, then use back-references:

```
(.*)([0-9]{3}.*)
```

with the replacement being:

```
\1p\2
```

For more details, see `pydoc re` that will tell you about Python regular expression syntax, or the [online documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Kees says, the plugin uses Python's `re` module syntax, which also has a [How-To](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) on the python site.

I also recommend installing and playing around with [kodos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kodos) [image: Install kodos] .
It's a python regular expression tester (it calls itself a 'debugger'), and includes a quick reference regex sheet as well as a shorter version of the `re` module documentation.

The [regular-expression.info site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) has a nice comparison of different implementations of regular expression meta-languages.  There's a decent section on the python flavor there as well.

Comment: @igbelacqua: Thanks! I guess Kodos is for KDE. If I am correct, it can be installed on Gnome but not the best if there is some other native software for Gnome. Do you know what the natives are?

Comment: Hmm -- Kodos does have Qt dependencies, but it's not a KDE app per se that I can see.  I run basic Ubuntu (Gnome), and it hasn't been out of place .  Another option is `kiki` -- it's a  python-wxgtk2.6
 application -- not as full-featured.  I used it before finding kodos.    

Another tester option that doesn't require an install is http://www.pythonregex.com/ -- it says it was inspired by Kodos, and it's clean and useful.  It's possibly the easiest to use of the three.