# What regex flavor does gedit support?

Tags: gedit, regex

On Ubuntu 20.04, my version of gedit 3.36.2 came with a regex checkbox for Find and Replace out of the box without installing any plugins. Which regex flavor is used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about using Regex Search & Replace in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30407/questions-about-using-regex-search-replace-in-gedit)

Comment: @zwets no, that is for a specific gedit plugin. Unless it has been incorporated into later gedit releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok looking through the source code I found [`gtk_source_search_settings_set_regex_enabled`](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtksourceview/gtksourceview5/method.SearchSettings.set_regex_enabled.html) which links to [GLib's regex](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.Regex.html) which is "similar to Perl's" and uses PCRE ([this Wireshark Q&A](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/45368/is-regex-lookaround-supported-in-wireshark-display-filters/) suggests it has different defaults.)